# Theme_image() returns nothing

Tags: drupal-6

I'm stuck on a roadblock with the simplest of things. In Drupal 6, I'm trying to take a user-entered path to an image and output that image to the page. Here's a bit of code:

```
$slogan_image = theme('image', $slogan_image_path);
dpm("\$slogan_image_path = '$slogan_image_path'");
dpm("\$slogan_image = '$slogan_image'");
```

The devel output reads:

```
$slogan_image_path = '/sites/default/files/images/Family.jpg'
$slogan_image = ''
```

There is an image at '/sites/default/files/images/Family.jpg'; if I browse to `www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/images/Family.jpg`, the image will be displayed.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my path began with a slash. Drupal paths don't have that initial slash. Drupal being open source, I could look refer to [the Drupal 6 api docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6) and see the code for theme_image included this line:

```
$url = (url($path) == $path) ? $path : (base_path() . $path);
```

showed me that Drupal would prepend my path with the base_path(). Executing that code myself, in an Execute PHP page, allowed me to see that theme_image would wind up using `//sites/default/files/images/Family.jpg` as the $url, clearly an illegal value.

I thought I'd append this short explanation to my trivial problem to help rank beginners see how I debugged it.